# Drawing first 4 letters of name in 3d on eclipse

Tags: java

[image]

This is number 3 by the way but my teacher wants us to do our first 4 letters of our name like John. Instead of Java.
Any tips on how to do this elliptical illusion.

Answer (score 2):

Don't over think this. Your task is to just print the exact stuff it wants to the screen.  Write it out in a string and print it.

If you wanted to get fancy to print ASCII art for each letter, do it for each letter, and store it in a dictionary and look up the string representation to display.

This task is more menial labor than anything else

Answer (score 1):

I am confused as to what exactly the learning objective of this exercise is. However, given the task you have, I would recommend first drawing it, and considering how you would represent it in characters. I would assume that then you need to create a similar output using System.out.println